# Можно ли использовать curl для протокола SIP?

Tags: curl, sip

Если нельзя, то какой самый простой способ послать REGISTER на сип-сервер и посмотреть ответ? Как проще всего это сделать из консоли?

Comment: можно вообще руками вбивать текстовый протокол в telnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, с помощью `netcat` (nc): запрос из файла sip.reg на локально запущенный сервер:

```
cat reg.sip | nc -u localhost 5060
```

Если сервер умеет работать с SIP по tcp, то можно и с помощью telnet.

Но в ответ придёт, скорее всего, 401, и повторный запрос руками создать довольно сложно. Расширенное средство создания сценариев для протокола SIP - утилита `sipp`, она позволяет реализовыввать более сложные сценарии, в основном - для нагрузочного тестирования.
Наконец, можно найти SIP клиент (LinPhone, например), который умеет писать в лог обмен с сервером.